# iPad wont charge in India

Tags: ipad, charging

I am not sure why my iPad will not charge in India which I got in US. Did the power fluctuations kill the charging part or do I need to charge it in some other way? How do I test or find out the reason why the iPad wont charge?
It was charging well for a year and now it does not.

I am using the charger for iPad and not the iPhone. Help me. Thanks.

Comment: What does the text on the charger say? Does it say anything like 220-240V?

Comment: I took the US charger to India and it was fine for almost a year.. Now it is having the issue of not charging. When I connect it to a wall charger the green empty battery sign comes up, but wont charge.

Comment: Your charger is dead. Buy a new one.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the same problem. Despite using Apple charger and lead the iPad thinks it's a copy and delivers the prompt that my charger or lead is incompatible. I believe the problem is that the voltage in India can waiver because this only happens at peak power usage times.